# Using the memset() and interpreting the size_t num of the funciton

Tags: c, string, pointers, strlen, memset

I am trying to decipher a block of code that uses `memset()`. Below is what I am trying to decipher.

```
memset(buffer, 0, strlen(argv[1]) - 4);
```

From my understanding of the memset function, it is to fill the block of memory of "buffer" with the value of "0"  and return the size of the string stored in `argv[1] -4`. Can someone explain `argv[1] -4`?

I understand that `argv[1]` is the first array to be set into the buffer.

I used resources from [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset), the syntax for `memset()` is

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

and the corresponding description is

> The `memset()` function fills the first `n` bytes of the memory area pointed to by `s` with the constant byte `c`.

So, as per the code,

```
memset(buffer, 0, strlen(argv[1]) - 4);
```

> memset function, it is to fill the block of memory of "buffer"

Right

> with the value of "0"

Right. its `0`, not `"0"`, though.

> and return the size of the string stored in "argv[1] -4 "

NO. the third argument of `memset()` is the ***size or amount of memory (in bytes) to be filled*** with the value supplied as the second argument.

For clarity and readibility, we can re-write the same as below

```
memset( buffer , 0 , (strlen(argv[1]) - 4) );
```

That said, `strlen(argv[1]) - 4` gives the *length* of the string held by `argv[1]`, subtracted by `4`. As very rightly suggested my Mr. **@Paul R**, this logic is most probably used to denote the filename *without* an extension / suffix (omit last 4 `chars` of the input string).

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is the argument (or more precisely a sequence of strings) handed over to the `main` function, defined while invoking the program.

Typically the `main` function has a form:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
```

where `argc` - number of input arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely initialising a buffer to hold something like a filename with the suffix removed, e.g. if the program is invoked as:

```
my_program my_filename.txt
```

then `argv[1]` contains the string "my_filename.txt". So `strlen(argv[1]) - 4` would therefore be 15 - 4 = 11, i.e. enough characters to hold the string "my_filename" (without a terminating character).

Answer (score 0):

`argv[1]` is the value that we enter when the program is executed (command line argument).The `memset()` in your code sets `buffer` to `0` till `argv[1]-4` is reached. ie. if you provide `10` then `10-4=6` , buffer will be set to 0 for 6 bytes